# Function name vs Ordinal value - Getting function address from a DLL module

Tags: c++, c, windows, dll

I have a DLL (WinDll.dll) that exports a function called 'SampleFunction'. The DLL is in the same folder as that of the executing application. Now when I try getting the address of the exported function by name, it gives error `127`, however, when I do the same using the ordinal value of the function, it works all fine. Any ideas how and why this might be happening?? Following is the code which loads and tries to make use of the exported function. Also I have attached a clip from IDA Proo that shows the exported functions from WindDll.dll.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef int (WINAPI *ProcP)(HINSTANCE, HINSTANCE, LPSTR, int);

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    HINSTANCE hinstlib;
    LPSTR lpBuffer = (LPSTR)malloc(256*2);
    GetCurrentDirectory(256,lpBuffer);
    ProcP procAddress = NULL;

    strcat(lpBuffer,"\\WinDll.dll");
    hinstlib = LoadLibrary(TEXT(lpBuffer));

    if(hinstlib == NULL){
        MessageBox(NULL,lpBuffer, "Bull", MB_OK);
        exit(0);
    }
    else{
        procAddress = (ProcP)GetProcAddress(hinstlib,"SampleFunction");    // <-- Problem
        if(procAddress != NULL){
            PostMessage(NULL, WM_RBUTTONDOWN, MK_RBUTTON, 0);   
        }
        else{
            MessageBox(NULL, "Invalid ProcAddress", "Bull", MB_OK); 
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

[image: IDA Snapshot]
[image: Dumpbin Snapshot]

Comment: Have you specified that SampleFunction is exported by the dll?

Comment: From the screenshot it looks like the name of the exported function is more than just `SampleFunction`

Comment: Try the dumpbin command like this: `dumpbin /exports WinDll.dll` and show us the output. Maybe it's a calling convention problem. Is `SampleFunction` declared with `__cdecl` ?

Comment: Added dumpbin snapshot.

Answer (score 3):

The `SampleFunction` seems to be declared with the _stdcall calling convention. So the name of the function you must pass to `GetProcAddress` is "_SampleFunction@16" as showed by the dumpbin command.

For more details about calling convention search for `_stdcall`, `_cdecl` and `Calling convetion`.

Comment: Strange! It worked. I may surmise why the preceding `_` but what do the trailing `@16` denote?

Comment: @16 - is size of parameters passed.